# Continuous Integration in Salesforce for Packaging Orgs with Jenkins, Bit Bucket

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, production, jenkins, ci

We have different Packing orgs in our company with different functionalities. we want to setup continuous integration with these orgs and Jenkins server. Could someone suggest me how to set up CI for Packaging orgs? Like the process, tools (if any) and do I need any more Sandboxes? Currently we have 4 orgs which acts as production and we have 4 staging orgs. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ravi,

Have you watched any of the Dreamforce presentations on the subject? There's usually one every year.

Here's one I gave in 2013. Not much has changed.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0u1CBUsj_I

Let me know if you have any specific questions.

-Ted.